# How to determine the bit order allocation at compile time?

Tags: c++

as we all known, for some compilers:

```
struct T{
    char bits: 4; // 3:0
};
```

and for others:

```
struct T{
    char bits: 4; // 7:4
};
```

since this is not specified by the standard. ( I do think this (the arithmetic meaning) should be specified by the standard, and the actual physical allocation is another issue that can't be specified. )

However, I want my code to be more generic, so I tried:

```
union helper{
    unsigned char b:1;
    unsigned char c;
    constexpr helper(unsigned char i): c(i){}
};

constexpr int lsb_defined_at_top(){ return helper(1).b;}

enum{
    LSB_AT_DEFINED_AT_TOP = lsb_defined_at_top()
};
```

but the compiler (gcc 4.7.2) complains:

error: accessing 'helper::b' member instead of initialized 'helper::c' member in constant expression

I wonder is there any way to determine this at compile time ...

Comment: What is `3:0` and `7:4`?

Comment: You could just use std::bitset and not care about the order?

Comment: @Nawaz bit position 3 - 0 (low 4bits) or 7 - 4 (high 4bits) in a byte

Comment: There's special instructions on some CPUs to do efficient bit-field operaitons (BFI on cortex-m3 for example). I tend to define bit-field so that the compiler may optimize better.

Comment: @Martin Beckett   - the order is importent when programming the low level register for mcu. so std::bitset can't help me :-)

Comment: Or, you can not use bitfields...

Comment: @Pony279 then I would use masks and bit operations directly. ps you can convert a bitset to/from ULONG to get a 'real' value - although probably not best option on a "micro"-micro.

Comment: @Martin Beckett  --- I'm using the masks and bit operations for a long time. I read the dis-asm code to find out that gcc can't use the special instruction to optimize the code. Then I tried bit-field, the gcc did optimize better.

Comment: I can do the run-time check only at start up . If assertion fails, I would redefine some macro only once. This may solve everything.

Comment: I have long preached the evils of bit fields, and avoid them like the plague.  They are very implementation dependent, and are the biggest cause of problems when moving code between platforms and/or compilers.  (As people at my current job have been finding out recently.)

The only way to be sure is to stick to allocating your own bits and accessing them explicitly.  Whether you do this by hand, or define some helper macros/functions/classes is up to you.  Just as long as you avoid bit fields.  :)

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1188 explains why this doesn't work from a standards perspective.